# can anyone give me a resolution to the following error? I am trying to run tests in react using Jest but getting an error for imports

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

myComponent.test.js

```
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import { myComponent } from '../components/myComponent.component'

it("fetches data", async () => {
    var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
    const data = { response: true };
    mock.onGet('https://api.github.com/users').reply(200,data )

})
```

Then I am trying to run jest and my test suite is failing and pointing to the following :
{"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

Error is as follows

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript 
(../../../../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
```

Comment: package.json :"jest": {
    
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[^(node_modules)]"
    ]
  }

Comment: what are you trying to achieve are you running any test cases using jest and enzyme ?

Comment: Give a title with better explanation, so that  others can search and us this question

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes i am running test cases using jest

Comment: can you add some more explanation, it will be easy to help you out. What are you trying to achieve in which scenario whats the use case ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS  have installed jest and trying to run my test cases on js file. Trying to mock axios and I am getting an error on the following import as such.   ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS have installed jest and trying to run my test cases on js file. Trying to mock axios and I am getting an error on the following import as such. ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'; ^^^^^^^^^^^ –

Comment: @abcde post the code snippet and try to make it reproducible

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS please refer to the edited post now

Comment: @abcde I see two three things are not there importing axios, , setting the mock like var mock = new MockAdapter(axios); then doing an await ??

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS if I add import React from 'react'; even then I get the error. I get the error for any first import I doing

Comment: @abcde can you create the same issue in codesandbox so it will be helpful , same like create-react-app , you can add here https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-greider-fjisu